# Convert from JS to ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#

can someone convert this from JS to ASP.Net?

```
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = y+=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If, by *ASP.NET*, you mean *C#* then no. You can't convert the code.

This is because JavaScript runs in the Web browser in the context of a current page. There is no current page like this when you're running C# code.

Now, if you are using something like Web Forms, there is a way to locate and modify elements. But this is in the ASP.NET Web Forms model, and not the DOM like JavaScript uses.

Comment: I was looking for a way to connect two images from different pages. And couldn't find anything on google. For example if i change my profile picture in my profile page, that image should also change on another page.

Comment: The page should normally load the image from a database or session setting when the page loads. Other than that, you haven't given near enough context to answer definitively.